# How to update from a unsupported version of ubuntu to latest?

Tags: updates

How can I update my Ubuntu version (11.04) to the latest version without any disks/USB drives?

I am currently running 11.04 (Just installed it) and I cannot download any programs which is the main thing I do with my computer, so I would like to update so I can do so.

How may I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well in order to be able to do that, you'll need to go from 11.o4 --> 11.10 --> 12.04 and then 13.04.  Plus some of your installed software that was done under 11.04, might not work with 13.04.

I would recommend that you backup any information that you want to keep, and do a fresh install.

Also the fact that 11.04 has reached End-of-life.  End-of-life releases are versions of Ubuntu that have no official support. So it would be best to perform a fresh install of the latest Ubuntu release.

Now if you still want to go the upgrade route, then take a look at [Upgrade Notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes).

Answer (score 0):

Go to search, type update, and an update manager will appear.  When you open then, you will likely be prompted to upgrade to 12.04, and if not, at the top right hand corner of the window, there should be an upgrade to 12.04 now button.